# Cyberduck requesting password to ssh into ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, cyberduck

I am using cyberduck to login to an EC2 instance.  I do not have a password, only a valid .pem key file.  My intuition is that Cyberduck does not recognize my .pem file and is therefore requesting a password.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "login to an EC2 instance"? Cyberduck does not support SSH. Are you referring to connecting via SFTP?

Answer (score 0):

In the Connection or the Bookmark window in Cyberduck select *Use Public Key Authentication* and choose the private key. Refer to the [wiki](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/sftp#PublicKeyAuthentication)

Answer (score 0):

My error, I was trying to ssh into the wrong instance.  Cyberduck works correctly.